# Доступ к буферу обмена в Firefox 23.0.1

Tags: javascript, firefox

Как на чистом JavaScript (без всяких ZeroClipboard) скопировать в буфер обмена какой-то текст? В *about:config* могу делать что угодно. Скрипт не для общего пользования, а для меня. Пусть он не работает ни в одном браузере, ни на одном компьютере - плевать. Главное, пусть работает у меня на *Firefox 23.0.1, Windows 7*. Что для этого нужно?

Спасибо.

Comment: расширение напишите

и вот [ещё инфо](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/editor/midasdemo/securityprefs.html)

Comment: а готовых решений нет?

Comment: ну вот там в info готовое решение, апи смотрите где-то в примерах.

Answer (score 1):

Сам код весьма прост: `document.execCommand('copy')`.

Но поскольку давать произвольным веб-страницам доступ к буферу обмена не комильфо (представьте - реклама в буфере обмена:), условия, при которых он выполняется ограничены.

Раньше Firefox поддерживал его выполнение [только при условии установки специальных значений `capability.policy.*` в about:config](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Granting_JavaScript_access_to_the_clipboard).

[Начиная с Firefox 41 можно копировать в буфер обмена в ответ на события типа click](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.dev.platform/oWhmLMvGAD0/discussion), поэтому пример ниже должен работать в "чистом" Firefox:

```html
<p>Здесь можно выбрать текст, который копировать</p>
<button onclick="document.execCommand('copy');">Копировать</button>
```